# Does contravariance and covariance means using also the same type?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, types, subtyping

I am quite confused. I stumbled upon the signature rules (referred also by B.Liskov in her work), which state:

> Contravariance of arguments. *m1* and *m2* have the same number of
>   arguments. If the list of argument types of *m1* is *a*, and that of *m2*
>   is *b*,  then ∀i . *a<sub>i</sub>* < *b<sub>i</sub>* //meaning that *a* is subtype of *b*.

From another teaching material:

> For a function type DY→CY to be a subtype of (I.e., substitutable for)
>   DX→CX , we **must** be covariant in the result type, but contravariant in
>   the argument type!

So does it mean I never do proper subtyping if I use just the same types of arguments and return types? I do not understand whether using the same type also counts, i.e. when I use the same type for both the parent and child class method arguments, is this contravariant?

In other words, as c# does not allow arguments contravariance, does it mean my code is never LSP compliant? As I read that LSP requires that arguments must be contravariant..

```
class Person
{
}
class Employee: Person
{
}

class PersonRegister
{
   GetJobTitle(Employee e) {return e.JobTitle;}
}

class DeriverRegister: PersonRegister
{
  GetJobTitle(Person p)  //contravariance, using less derived type, cannot be done in C#
}
```

How this could work if e.g. the less derived type does not have the field required, in this example JobTitle? That is property of an Employee but necessarily of a Person.

Comment: "I do not understand whether using the same type also counts" - in most formal contexts, "a is a subtype of b" is true if a and b are the same type, if that's what you're asking? The phrase "strict subtype" can be used when we wish to rule out a and b being the same type.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Basically yes. The guidelines to LSP say that arguments MUST be contravariant. Does it mean using the same type in both the parent and the child is satisfcatory and complies to that?

Comment: Your example using `GetJobTitle(param1)` would be much more helpful if you specified the type of `param1` as declared in the method definition.

Comment: @JohnWu Ok, the defined type would be Employee, so that Person is the less derived type and thus legal by contravariance rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Person
{
}
class Employee: Person
{
}

class PersonRegister
{
   GetJobTitle(Employee e) {return e.JobTitle;}
}

class DeriverRegister: PersonRegister
{
  GetJobTitle(Person p)  //contravariance, using less derived type, cannot be done in C#
}
```

You are correct. If you want `GetJobTitle` in `DervierRegister` to be considered an `override` of `GetJobTitle` from `PersonRegister`, it must use *exactly* the same types. You should be *allowed* to create this method as written, but it *shadows* the one from `PersonRegister` and is not considered to be an override. So you can write the above, but

```
var e = new Employee();
PersonRegister pr = new DervierRegister();
pr.GetJobTitle(e);
```

Will invoke the method from `PersonRegister`.

> does it mean my code is never LSP compliant?

To the extent that you cannot use covariance and contravariance *generally*, yes. However, for generic [interfaces and delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance), support was added in C# 4.0. And also, as discussed, when speaking formally every type is considered to be a subtype of itself so phrases such as "*a* is subtype of *a*" are true for all types *a*.

Comment: And that is what I do not get - why it is said that arguments need to be contravariant for proper subtyping? How could it work if the less derived type has less information?

Comment: @JohnV - do you have links to the materials you've quoted in your question? I feel like I'm missing some surrounding context and neither of them themselves refers to "proper subtyp[ing]".

Comment: Sure. The first comes directly from the famous paper of Barbara Liskov and J.Wing: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~wing/publications/LiskovWing94.pdf see at 1827 (Signature rule)

Comment: @JohnV - okay, so if we accept that the rules of C# are *stricter* than the rules outlined in that paper, specifically that the general language rules of C# state that a<sub>i</sub> and b<sub>i</sub> have to be the same types (and the same applies for return types), both the covariance and contravariance rules are *trivially* satisfied.

Comment: I struggle with general understanding why arguments should be contravariant. If a base class uses in its method Employee object, how could it work with Person object in the derived class override, if Person has less data?

Comment: Also, covariance in return types does work in C# - I can return a more specific type (e.g. for a method returning Base, I can return Derived).

Comment: @John V - if the *implementation* of the derived class's `GetJobTitle` method only uses functionality of the `Person` class and doesn't rely on any of its `Employee`ness (including not calling the base class's `GetJobTitle` method) then (in theory) it can be declared with the type `Person`. In C# it cannot. And no, you cannot change the return type in the *signature*.

Comment: You are right, not in the signature. I was thinking just in the terms of returned values. As you say, if the method does not rely on any Employee-ness..but then the substitution principle says any derived class could replace the base class.

Comment: In your example, you mentioned that the method from PersonRegister will be invoked, but it will not. It will invoke the one from DerivedRegister. (I even tried).

Comment: @JohnV - yeah, I forgot what the example I was putting together was meant to demonstrate, and my default for declaring variables is `var` but in this case, that variable was meant to have a declare type of `PersonRegister`